# Why we used Visual studio code instead of the Visual Studio in higher version of angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

Hi all i started working on higher version of angular (angular 2 and Angular 4)
the first question in my mind is that why should we using visual studio code instead of the VS15 and VS17...I am used to visual studio due to which i am not finding VS Code Devlopment friendly.

Comment: you can use any IDE that a matter of choice. You can use Atom, VIM and so on..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic about what questions are on-topic here.

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio Code is more lightweight and runs on all platforms (being built on Election). Full Visual studio is Windows only, and some functionalities are not available in the free edition (community).

So for developing browser (cross-platform) applications, VS Code is a more logical choice.

Comment: Thanks @Mario Cianciolo.

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio Code is more lightweight than Visual Studio and can run on any platform